# How to construct an n-gon by ruler and compass?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, geometric-construction

Since $\cos[\frac{2\pi}{15}] $ is algebraic and equal to  $\frac{1}{8}(1+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{30-6\sqrt{5}})$ we know that the regular 15-gon is constructible by ruler and compass.

Although I know how to construct a hexagon by ruler and compass and have seen the construction of a pentagon done in a youtube video, I can't find a description of a general approach to constructing n-gons where $n>7$ anywhere.

Is there a general approach, geometric algorithm if you like, to constructing an n-gon by ruler and compass?

Comment: Great post +1 Knowing that it can be done is one thing, how to do it is another. That happens a lot in math...

Comment: You can't do it for general $n$. The only odd primes you can construct are the Fermat primes $3,5,17,65537$ No more are known. You can do products of there, but only first powers and multiply by any power of $2$

Comment: @RossMillikan So, there is no known algorithm for the construction of the n of which we know that they are theoretically constructible. Perhaps the realm of the ' theoretically possible ' is not within our reach.

Comment: We have procedures for the constructions I listed.  All others are proven to be impossible, basically because the trig functions of the required angles are not of the proper type (representable with arithmetic functions and square roots)

Comment: @RossMillikan You forgot to mention 257, it is also a fermat prime. $2^{2^3}+1=257$.

Comment: Well, most can't be constructed using a ruler and compass, but all can be constructed using trigonometry. Here's some code I wrote up: https://gist.github.com/avighnac/eeb8db61e83547b6d7acb7b636a1e64e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to construct an angle equal to $\frac{2\pi}{15}$, you just need to construct an equilateral triangle and a regular pentagon, since:
$$ \frac{2\pi}{15} =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{2\pi}{5}\right).$$
Have a look at the Wikipedia page about [contructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon) regular polygons.

Comment: I am looking for a general approach really. I will edit the question.

Comment: @ndroock1: the Wikipedia page deals with that. The point is that you just need to understand which polygons with a prime number of sides are constructible to know which numbers are associated with constructible polygons.

Comment: Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon Really ? Have you ever tried to do a construction other than those in the text books?

Comment: @ndroock1: I do not understand your point, what textbooks have to do with my answer? That Wikipedia page gives the number of sides of any constructible regular polygon. The explicit construction obviously depends on the root of a polynomial we are constructing through $+,-,*,/$ and $\sqrt{\cdot}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you can read French (purely mathematical), you'll find [on this page](http://therese.eveilleau.pagesperso-orange.fr/pages/truc_mat/textes/polygones_5_15_17.htm) applets for the geometric construction of the pentagon, and the penta- & heptadecagons.

Comment: The applets are only demonstrations of isolated cases without any explanation.

Comment: Yes, but the demonstrations are informative. It's a good exercise to prove what is implicitly asserted.